# Wrong name on Mail app

Tags: mail.app, email, calendar, gmail

I'm using Yosemite and I've added my `Google account` to my `Internet Accounts` and when I receive emails to that account the name is displayed as `Holidays in New Zealand`. This is somehow funny and wrong.

Just when I disable the `Calendar` item under my `Internet Accounts > Google` my email is displayed right on Mail.

All my details under `Mail` (Full Name, etc) are right.

How can I still have my Calendar linked and my name displayed under my Mail  app?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with the exact same name, its amusing by feels somewhat intrusive

I think i have fixed it by clicking the drop down menu by "Holidays in New Zealand" and clicking 'remove from previous recipients list'

hope this helps